# PHP/JavaScript variable to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, variables

I am using integration NodeJS and PHP, MySQL. And I have problem.
When I wan't to save chat message i need to get 'username' from 'index.php'. With javascript i did var username = "";

How can I do that in NodeJS? To use variable from 'index.php'.

Comment: Need to do a lot more explaining considering you are using multiple languages and environments

Comment: Thats way too little information. HOW are you possibly integrating NodeJS into PHP (or vice versa)?